# error to append integer in c++ boost python list

Tags: c++, python-2.7, boost-python

I maked this code and it does not work

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

bp::list points;

int one = 1;
int two = 2;
int three = 3;
points.append(one); #crach!!
points.append(two);
points.append(three);

return 0;}
```

which is the reason why "append" does not accept integers and directly which would be the correct way?

**edited**

the solution is this:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Py_Initialize(); //this part
bp::list points;

int one = 1;
int two = 2;
int three = 3;
points.append(one); #crach!!
points.append(two);
points.append(three);
    Py_Finalize(); //this part
return 0;}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are supposed to use `boost::python::list` from within the exported module, not from a C++ program directly. The reason for this is simple: `boost::python::list` is a wrapper around a Python list object and to work with it you need a Python interpreter which is not available when you try to operate on the list from your `main` method.

Here's a working example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

bp::list getlist() {
  bp::list points;
  int one = 1;
  int two = 2;
  int three = 3;
  points.append(one);
  points.append(two);
  points.append(three);
  return points;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(listtest) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("getlist", getlist);
}
```

Compiling this module and running the `getlist` function shows that everything works as expected:

```
>>> import listtest
>>> print listtest.getlist()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: that is true, but I make a main program to debug that functions.

Comment: I think you have two options: either debug it by calling from Python or embed a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks like a template method. So, you can try

```
 points.append<int>(one);
```

Comment: thanks a lot but that not fix the problem ... where is that documentation?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because the template argument would be deduced anyway even if you dont mention at callsite.